# How to put an Api call in an foreach

Tags: php, api

```
$a = array("com", "co", "net", "nl");
@$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$arr =  explode(".", $q);

$output = array();
foreach ($a as &$value) {
    if (substr($value, 0, strlen(@$arr[1])) === @$arr[1])
        $output[]= $arr[0] . "." . $value;
}
echo implode('<br>',$output);
```

So this is my code right now, what it does is it shows some domain names once I type a dot down. Now what I have is a Api that will see if the domain name typed in, is available or not once I click enter. But the **$output** shows some domain names. So for example typing "bol.c" I will see **"bol.com, bol.co, bol.co.uk"** and what I want is showing than and there automatically what the availabilty is without clicking a button, for example showing **bol.com** in the color red because it`s not available anymore.
[Img of what I have now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2uL4.png)

Can you guys give me some advice on how to do that, I use an Api of TransIP.

Comment: I'd use AJAX. When you detect a dot `.` being typed in, you can send API calls from JavaScript with AJAX for every letter typed in after the dot. Before the dot could also be possible, but probably isn't as useful.

Comment: Did you ask a similar question a few weeks ago (with a different username)? This seems very familiar.